# Understanding PDF text rotation with reportLab library

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to rotate a text in PDF by 180 degrees or in some cases 270 degrees, but here I am observing weird behavior whereas the rotating angle increases the text keeps on shifting to the left side.

[image: Text with 90-degree rotation]

[image: Text with 100-degree rotation]

[image: Text with 110-degree rotation]

[image: Text with 120-degree rotation]

First image is text with 90 degree rotation, second image is text with 100 degree rotation 3rd is with 110 degree rotation and finally 4th image is with 120-degree rotation. Because of this behavior when I rotate text with 180 degrees is it not visible on-page. Because it is present on the left side of the pdf. Can anyone help me understand this behavior and also how can I write text rotated by 180 and 270 degrees in PDF?